# Reseting gitk GUI

Tags: git, gitk

Today I worked as usual on my tasks but from one moment to the next, my gitk GUI was all mixed up:

[image]

Is there a way to reset the GUI/configure positions of GUI elements for gitk?

Comment: I guess `rm ~/.config/git/gitk` ?

Comment: yes, that solved it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man gitk`:

```
   User configuration and preferences are stored at:
   •   $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/gitk if it exists, otherwise
   •   $HOME/.gitk if it exists
   If neither of the above exist then $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/gitk is created and used by default. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set it
   defaults to $HOME/.config in all cases.
```

Removing the configuration, typically in `.config/git/gitk` should reset the settings.